# React Query // How to properly use client-state and server-state (when user can drag/sort items on the UI)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have an React App using React Query to load a dataset of `folders` containing `items`. The app allows the user to drag/sort items (within a folder and drag to another folder). Before implementing drag/sort it was simple, RQ fetched the dataset `folderData` and then the parent supplied data to child components: parent > `folder` > `item` .

In order to implement drag/sort, I am now having to copy the entire dataset `folderData` into a client-state variable `foldersLocal`. This is the only way I could figure out how to change the UI when the user moves an item.

However, I feel like this approach essentially removes most of the benefits of using React Query because as soon as the data is fetched, I copy the entire dataset into a "client-side" state variable (`foldersLocal`) and only work with it. This also makes the `QueryClientProvider` functionality effectively useless.

Is there a better way to approach this? Or am I missing something?

```
// Fetch data using React Query
const {isLoading, isError, foldersData, error, status} = useQuery(['folders', id], () => fetchFoldersWithItems(id));

// Place to hold client-state so I can modify the UI when user starts to drag/sort items
const [foldersLocal, setFoldersLocal] = useState(null);

// Store React Query data in client-state everytime it's fetched
useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'success') {
        setFoldersLocal(foldersData);
    }
}, [foldersData]);

// Callback to change "foldersLocal" when user is dragging an item
const moveItem = useCallback((itemId, dragIndex, hoverIndex, targetFolderId) => {
    setFoldersLocal((prevData) => {
        // change data, etc. so the UI changes
    }
}

// Drastically simplified render method
return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>         
        <FolderContainer folders={foldersLocal} moveItem={moveItem} moveItemCompleted={moveItemCompleted}/>
    </QueryClientProvider>
)
```

Comment: This comment might be the solution? https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/1270#discussioncomment-126129

Comment: yes, I think this is the answer ⬆️

Comment: @TkDodo Thanks for responding - I've read many of your blog posts!  I actually wanted to expand on that discussion (in the link above). My specific situation allows the user to sort items within a folder and also to to drag items to another folder. Keeping track of the sort within a folder is manageable (per the suggested solution). However, also keeping tack of parent folderIds before a write to server is extremely tricky because the parent>child (folder>item) dataset relationship is now invalid. I can no longer use QueryClientProvider to query "items" from a "folderId".

Comment: I am wondering if in this specific case React Query isn't really the right tool to solve the problem?